# Trouble setting up jquery pjax with Django (header not set, but GET parameter added)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, pjax

I've spent a while debugging why my pjax setup isn't working - here is what I know so far. 2 requests are happening within the same second. This is odd because I have a timeout set on the front end for 3 seconds.

```
[02/Nov/2014 05:42:26] "GET /i/feed/?_pjax=%23pjax HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[02/Nov/2014 05:42:26] "GET /i/feed/ HTTP/1.1" 200 62358
```

On the client:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).pjax('a[data-pjax]', '#pjax',
        {'timeout': 3000});
});
```

On the html (the pjax target exists):

```
<div id="pjax" class="cl-mcont">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

Also, the HTTP header is never detected. I have this snippet:

```
base_template = ('pjax.html' if request.META.get('HTTP-X-PJAX') 
        else 'base_v2.html')
```

base_template is always base_v2.html.

I am confused as to why pjax is able to modify the url, and cause an extra request to be sent, but at the same time, not setting the header correctly.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `HTTP` header should be `HTTP_X_PJAX` (underscore concatenated instead of dash) not `HTTP-X-PJAX`. As the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) states:

> Any HTTP headers in the request are converted to META keys by converting all characters to uppercase, replacing any hyphens with underscores and adding an HTTP_ prefix to the name. So, for example, a header called X-Bender would be mapped to the META key HTTP_X_BENDER

For the double events(request) firing, make sure you are not binding the `a[data-pjax]` selector twice with `pjax`. The binding should be done only once.

Answer (score 2):

Add to your view

```
print request.META
```

and just watch, what you got in header.